# Can't use javascript within Razor pages

Tags: javascript, c#, identityserver4, razor-pages

I have a razor page (login of Identity Server 4).
I'm trying to store a variable in local storage, for that I used a javascript file "StayLogged.js" that contains the following code:

```
document.getElementById("RememberLoginDiv").addEventListener("click", savetoLocal);

function savetoLocal() {
    var value = document.getElementById("RememberLogin").value;
    console.log(value);
    storage.setItem("RememberLogin", value);
}
```

The razor page has the following code:

```
@model Security.Api.Controllers.Authentication.Account.LoginViewModel

<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />

<div class="login-page page-container-login">



    <div class="row">

        @if (Model.EnableLocalLogin)
        {
            <div class="content-justify ui-widget page-container-login width-hundred position-login ">
                <div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive ui-grid-pad ui-fluid  d-flex login-container-form  flex-column bd-highlight mb-3 login-container-form">
                    <img src="../INVOLYS-blanc.png" class="mb-auto p-2 bd-highlight login-form-logo" alt="add" />
                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 p-2 bd-highlight mb-4">
                        <div class="login-form">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-12 login-form-header">
                                    <div class="text-align-centre login-form-header-title">
                                        <span>Praxis</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <form asp-route="Login">
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="ReturnUrl" />
                                <div class="text-align-centre login-form-content">
                                    <div>
                                        <label class="mt-4" asp-for="Username">Utilisateur</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" asp-for="Username" autofocus>
                                        <label class="mt-4" asp-for="Password">Mot de passe</label>
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" asp-for="Password" autocomplete="off">


                                        @if (Model.AllowRememberLogin)
                                        {
                                            <div id="RememberLoginDiv" class="form-group login-remember">
                                                <label class="mt-4" asp-for="RememberLogin">
                                                    <input asp-for="RememberLogin">
                                                    <strong>Se souvenir de ma connexion</strong>
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        }
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary button-content " name="button" value="login">Se connecter</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <button class="btn btn-default button-content  mb-4" name="button" value="forgetPassword">
                                                Mot de passe oublie
                                            </button>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <partial name="_ValidationSummary" />

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }


        @if (!Model.EnableLocalLogin && !Model.VisibleExternalProviders.Any())
        {
            <div class="alert alert-warning">
                <strong>Invalid login request</strong>
                There are no login schemes configured for this client.
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>


@section scripts {
    <script src="../Views/Account/StayLogged.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

But I can't load my javascript file, nor do save my item on local storage, even if I tried to put the script inside the tags, it gave me a security error.

Comment: You mean `localStorage.setItem` or `sessionStorage.setItem`  - there is no `storage`

Comment: What is the security error? Is it Content-Security-Policy related?

Comment: I meant localStorage, but there is that error who says that the .js file isnt found even if I embeded it etc..

Answer (score 0):

To add file:
`@section scripts {<script src="@Url.Content(".....")" type="text/javascript"}></script>`

To save into local storage:
 `window.localStorage.setItem('name', 'value');`

Comment: It still gives me the same error: `GET https://localhost:5005/Account/StayLogged.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404`

Comment: Probably the path where the file is located is not correct.